# data structure for file path string find insert delete

Tags: c, linux, algorithm, data-structures

I monitor the filesystem event, and store event using path as key, when multiple event of a path occures i need find a the previous event and merge them.

which data structure and algorightm to store and find filesytem event based on path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a structure to describe each event, including the path as a C99 flexible array member:

```
struct event {
    /* Event queue pointers */
    struct event *queue_prev;
    struct event *queue_next;

    /* Event identifying bit mask */
    size_t        mask;

    /* Path hash table */
    struct event *hash_next;
    size_t        hash;
    unsigned char path[];
};
```

The event queue itself is a doubly linked list, to avoid having to walk through an entire linked list when removing an event based on the path.

Each hash table slot is a singly-linked list of events.  This is because we expect those chains to be short, otherwise the hash table is not efficient.

I am not sure which hash function would work best, but I'd start with good old DJB2:

```
size_t djb2(const unsigned char *src)
{
    size_t  hash = 5381;
    while (*src)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) ^ (*(src++));
    return hash;
}
```

The event queue and the path hash table would be described using

```
struct event_queue {
    /* Event queue */
    size_t        events;
    struct event *first;  /* First event in queue */
    struct event *last;   /* Last event in queue */
    /* Path hash table */
    size_t        slots;
    struct event *slot;
};
```

Since the cost of each path hash table slot is just one pointer, it is a good idea to start with a relatively large hash table, say 256 slots.  This is not a limit; it just gets slower (since one needs to traverse the slot chain).  It should probably be a configurable setting.  To initialize the event queue, I'd use

```
int event_queue_init(struct event_queue *queue, size_t slots)
{
    if (!queue || slots < 1)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    /* The queue itself is empty. */
    queue->events = 0;
    queue->first  = NULL;
    queue->last   = NULL;

    queue->slots  = slots;
    queue->slot   = calloc(slots, sizeof queue->slot[0]);
    /* Note: In Linux, queue->slot is now full of NULL pointers.
             This may not be true on other OSes! */

    if (!queue->slot)
        return errno = ENOMEM;
}
```

It can be a good idea to resize the hash table at run time, even though it is not strictly necessary:

```
int event_queue_resize(struct event_queue *queue, size_t slots)
{
    size_t i, n;

    if (!queue || slots < 1)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    struct event *slot[] = calloc(slots, sizeof slot[0]);
    if (!slot)
        return errno = ENOMEM;
    /* Note: In Linux, slot is now full of NULL pointers.
             This may not be true on all OSes! */

    n = 0;
    i = queue->slots;
    while (i-->0) {
        struct event *next = queue->slot[i];
        queue->slot[i] = NULL;
        while (next) {
            struct event *curr = next;
            size_t        slotnum = curr->hash % slots;

            next = next->hash_next;
            n++;

            curr->hash_next = slot[slotnum];
            slot[slotnum] = curr;
        }
    }
    free(queue->slot);
    queue->slots  = slots;
    queue->slot   = slot;
    queue->events = n;
}
```

It is safe to resize the hash table even when there are queued events, as the event queue pointers are not affected by the hash table resize.

To append an event to the queue, modifying the existing event for the same path if already queued:

```
int event_append(struct event_queue *queue,
                 const unsigned char *path,
                 size_t mask)
{
    if (!queue || !path)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    const size_t  hash = djb2(path);
    const size_t  slotnum = hash % queue->slots;

    struct event *ev = queue->slot[slotnum];
    while (ev) {
        if (ev->hash == hash && !strcmp(ev->path, path)) {

            /* Event already queued. */
            ev->mask |= mask;

            return 0;
        } else {
            ev = ev->hash_next;
        }
    }

    const size_t pathlen = strlen(path);

    ev = malloc(sizeof (struct event) + pathlen + 1);
    if (!ev)
        return errno = ENOMEM;

    memcpy(ev->path, path, pathlen + 1); /* Include '\0' at end */
    ev->hash = hash;
    ev->mask = mask;

    /* Prepend to hash table */
    ev->hash_next = queue->slot[slotnum];
    queue->slot[slotnum] = ev;

    /* Append to queue */
    if (!queue->first) {
        ev->queue_prev = NULL;
        ev->queue_next = NULL;
        queue->first = ev;
        queue->last = ev;
        queue->events = 1;
    } else {
        ev->queue_prev = queue->last;
        ev->queue_next = NULL;
        queue->last->queue_next = ev;
        queue->last = ev;
        queue->events++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To pop the next event in the queue:

```
struct event *event_next(struct event_queue *queue)
{
    if (!queue)
        return NULL;

    struct event *ev = queue->first;
    if (!ev)
        return NULL;

    queue->first = ev->queue_next;
    if (!queue->first) {
        queue->last = NULL;
        queue->events = 0;
    } else {
        queue->first->queue_prev = NULL;
    }

    ev->queue_prev = NULL;
    ev->queue_next = NULL;

    queue->events--;

    /* Remove from the hash table */
    struct event **ptr = queue->slot + ev->hash % queue->slots;
    struct event *evt = *ptr;
    while (evt) {
        if (evt == ev) {
            *ptr = ev->hash_next;
            break;
        } else {
            ptr = &(evt->hash_next);
            evt = *ptr;
        }
    }

    return ev;
}
```

To cancel event on a specific path:

```
struct event *event_dequeue(struct event_queue *queue,
                            const unsigned char *path)
{
    if (!queue || !path)
        return NULL;

    const size_t   hash = djb2(path);
    const size_t   slotnum = hash % queue->slots;
    struct event **ptr = queue->slot + slotnum;
    struct event  *ev = *ptr;

    while (ev) {
        if (ev->hash == hash && !strcmp(ev->path, path)) {
            /* Remove from event queue */
            if (ev->queue_prev)
                ev->queue_prev->queue_next = ev->queue_next;
            if (ev->queue_next)
                ev->queue_next->queue_prev = ev->queue_prev;
            if (queue->first == ev)
                queue->first = ev->queue_next;
            if (queue->last == ev)
                queue->last = ev->queue_prev;
            queue->events--;
            /* Remove from hash table slot */
            *ptr = ev->next;
            /* Done. */
            return ev;
        }

        ptr = &(ev->next);
        ev = *ptr;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

These are just off-the-cuff implementations to show you the idea; I'm sure you can implement them much better.

It is useful to note that you can move an event up/down in the queue using only the `queue_prev` and `queue_next` pointers, although you will also need to update the queue `first` and `last` pointers if you change either one.

For thread-safe operation, I would use a `pthread_mutex_t` in the `struct event_queue`, held during operations.  Each operation (except for hash table resize) takes so little time that the added code complexity allowing concurrent access is not worthwhile.

Comment: I test this hash function `h = h * 33 + c`  which is used in gnu elf symbol table, it hash exstreamly balanced, no same hash result, at 540 thounds path of my computer.

Comment: @yuanjianpeng: Yes, that's the same DJB hash function.  (There are two variants, one using '+' and the other using '^'; `(x << 5) + x == 33*x` for `x` of any unsigned integer type, and `size_t` is an unsigned integer type.)  It does work well for human-readable text in my experience, but as I haven't compared it against other hash functions, I didn't want to claim it is good/better than other hashes.